# Wordpress - Creating Json File

Tags: php, json, wordpress, file

I am having a problem while creating a json file using a wordpress plugin created by me. My code consists of reading data from my database, putting it in an array and than storing it as a json file.

I've tried to change the path of my json file to my desktop folder and it worked. I have tried to create a file using pure php on the same directory. And it worked also.

This is my code:

```
$fp = fopen('C:\Users\Home\Desktop\results.json', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response[0]));
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. It seems like WordPress has a problem with relative and absolute paths, so to avoid problems, it is better to use the WordPress function plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ), which will return the path to your plugin file(PHP file ) as a string and then concatenate it with the rest of your path and that's it. It works. and it's adaptative. (on Linux, it will return Linux path format and the same as windows)